# Is it possible to see what triggered an Azure VM reboot?

Tags: windows, azure, virtual-machines, windows-server-2019

I have received some email notifications from Azure, containing this:

```
Activity log alert  Alert [Server Name] Health Status  
Properties {
    "title":"Reboot initiated from inside the machine",
    "details":"A reboot was triggered from inside the virtual machine. This could be due to a virtual machine operating system failure or as requested by an authorized user or process. The virtual machine will be back online after the reboot completes.",
    "currentHealthStatus":"Unavailable",
    "previousHealthStatus":"Unavailable",
    "type":"Downtime",
    "cause":"UserInitiated" }
```

This definitely was not 'UserInitiated' but could have been caused by Windows Update as the time falls within the 'out of hours' window defined.

However, is there any way to tell in the logs what triggered the reboot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at "Resource health" to see if there are any other events in the history.
You are right, if it falls into the "out of hours" windows it was probably Windows Update. In our environment we get exactly these notifications when Windows Update triggers a reboot.

If you want to be 100% sure it was Windows Updates, filter the system Event Log for IDs 1074, 6006 and 6008. Look for an event at the reboot time. It should say something like this:

```
    The process C:\windows\system32\wbem\wmiprvse.exe (HOSTNAME) has initiated the restart of computer HOSTNAME on behalf of user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM for the following reason: No title for this reason could be found
 Reason Code: 0x80070015
 Shutdown Type: restart
 Comment:
```

Microsoft could have added a reason so it would be easier to identify why...

Comment: I see this message in both Windows Event Viewer and the Azure Resource Health logs, but they are four days earlier than the actual reboot.  There are no entries for yesterday when this happened.

Comment: Can't hardly imagine. Are you sure you are reading the timestamps correct? They might be in US-Stlye (MM/DD/YYYY). Could you be watching on the wrong machine? If there are no entries in both Event Viewer an Ressource Health then there was most likely no reboot.

Comment: OMG I blame stress.  Yes I was looking at the wrong machine - too many browser windows open... Thank you that's perfect and solves the mystery.  It would be nice if Microsoft made the message more meaningful!

Answer (score 3):

Your only/best chance is to look inside the VM into whatever logging is active there.

Azure tells you - obviously for anyone reading - that the reboot was triggered from INSIDE the VM. That is where the platform knowledge ends, the VM asks for a reboot.

Now, inside you MAY find more Information, but a lot really depends on OS, setup and - worst case - even no the applications (i.e. whether they even log this).

You will not find anything on Azure as the outside has no knowledge.

Also note:

> This definitely was not 'UserInitiated' but could have been caused by Windows
> Update as the time falls within the 'out of hours' window defined.

Per definition, from the point of view of the Azure environment, Windows Update running in the VM IS USER INITIATED. The user (i.e. the VM) asks for a reboot.
So, it is absolutely user initiated.

Comment: Can you advise where to check in the Windows VM logs please?  I am assuming Event Viewer, but which node(s) please?